# New computer slower at loading old program

Tags: multithreading, performance

I was unable to find any information (maybe I searched for the wrong terms??) about this topic so I thought I would ask.

*******I AM NOT TRYING TO SLAM ANYONE JUST ADDING A LITTLE BACKGROUND INFORMATION!!!*******

At my company, we have a piece of software that was written by someone who had no formal programming education.

We recently purchased a few new computers for my department and when opening a file with this piece of software, it puts the entire computational load on a single core and takes longer to open as compared to one of our old machines.

for example, an old computer has a Xeon W3550 and only needs about 30-45 seconds to load everything and the new computer has an i7-8700k and takes about 1.5 minutes or more to open the same file.

Could it be that the multi-threaded code isn't compatible with new processors? Could it be due to a lack of education from the original author?

any information would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The reason you didn't find any answer is because you can't answer this without looking at the code. And, I am sorry but this question is off topic here as well

Comment: Might also want to look at how/where the data is stored. E.g. I'd expect some performance differences if you went from "RAID mirror of SSDs without encryption" to "single rotating metal disk with encryption".